# Dynamic URLs in Kendo data-bind or attribute for list items

Tags: html, jquery, typescript, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have two menu items that I am trying to route conditionally using Kendo Jquery/MVVM.
Initially this value was set in a `data-href` tag and was rendering the url just fine, but I need to change this to conditionally load a url. This is a list item

.aspx

```
<li data-bind="attr: {invisible:bIsHuddles3FeatureEnabled, href: urlSource}">
<span>URL Option 1</span>
</li>
<br>
<li data-bind="attr: {invisible:bIsHuddles3FeatureEnabled, href: urlSource}">
<span class="nav-text">URL Option 2</span>
</li>
```

.ts

```
   urlSource: function () {
            let huddleURL = '';
            if (check I want to perform is true) {
                huddleURL = "/Application/URLOption1.aspx";
            } else {
                huddleURL = "/Application/URLOption2.aspx";
            }
            return huddleURL;
        }
```

Instead of routing me to the page I expect, I am rerouted to the main page of the application. I also tried this using `data-bind= "attr: {visible: anotherMethod, href: /Application/URLOption2.aspx}"`  in the `li` but received an error message `The href binding is not supported by the li element`. Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is it as simple as adding an <a> element and having the binding on that?

```
<li>
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: urlSource}"><span>URL Option 1</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: This is the way! Thank you @NigelK, seems very obvious now but I appreciate your response!